# If I upload Excel data to Rstudio Server Pro, can I delete columns to make subsets of the data?

Tags: r

I haven't been able to find a resource online yet. I have a large data set (115 columns) and am looking to delete some of the data in R because I'm not using it for certain graphs.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subset` function to remove columns from an `R` data frame. See the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/subset).

Examples:

```
# Remove column Col1 from dataframe df. Store the result in a data frame called new_df
new_df <- subset(df, select=-Col1)

# Remove columns Col1 and Col2 from dataframe df. Store the result in a data frame called new_df_2
new_df_2 <- subset(df, select=-c(Col1, Col2)
```